# How to create csv file in expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo, export-to-csv

I'm still new to React Native may I know how can I create csv file in react native using expo? I've seen people suggesting `expo-file-system` as they said it is not recommended to use `react-native-fs` if using expo but I not sure how to use it. is it using `FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, contents, options)`?

Comment: Does the answer below solves your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a function that creates a simple `.csv` file

I'm using `react-native-csv` to generate the `.csv`.
`expo-media-library` is used to move the file from a folder accessible from the app to a publicly accessible folder.

```js
import { jsonToCSV, readRemoteFile } from 'react-native-csv';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';

export async function makeCSV() {
  
  const jsonData = `[
    {
        "Column 1": "Name",
        "Column 2": "Surname",
        "Column 3": "Email",
        "Column 4": "Info"
    }
  ]`;

  const CSV = jsonToCSV(jsonData);

  // Name the File
  const directoryUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory;
  const fileUri = directoryUri + `formData.csv`;
  
  // Ask permission (if not granted)
  const perm = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.MEDIA_LIBRARY);
  if (perm.status != 'granted') {
    console.log("Permission not Granted!")
    return;
  }
  
  // Write the file to system
  FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, CSV)
  
  try {
    const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri);
    const album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync('forms');
    console.log(album)
    if (album == null) {
      await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('forms', asset, true);
    } else {
      await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album, true);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey Andre, I'm getting [Error: Could not create asset.], do you have any idea? inspite Directory exist, file exist, permissions granted

Comment: To properly answer your comment I would need to have more information. What extension, how the file was created and probably more. Maybe you can find some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73978374/how-to-create-a-pdf-or-csv-file-automatically-in-react-native-for-android-11 or make your own question. If you do feel free to send me the link.