# How to create a .pdf or .csv file automatically in React Native for Android 11 (or later)

Tags: react-native, expo

The following code works up to Android 10, it is creating a `csv` file in the DCIM folder:

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';

export async function saveCSV() {
      
  const permission = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
  if (permission.status != 'granted') {
    console.log("Permission not Granted!")
    return;
  }
  
  // CSVLocation
  const directoryUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory;
  const fileUri = directoryUri + `formData.csv`;
  
  // Save to DCIM folder
  const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri);
  
  try {
    const album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync('album');
    if (album == null) {
      console.log("ASSET", asset)
      await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('album', asset, true);
    } else {
      await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album, true)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('File Saved Successfully!');
        })
        .catch((err: string) => {
          console.log('Error In Saving File!', err);
        });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

}
```

Previously this line of code was executed in another function to create a file in the `fileUri` used above:

```
await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, CSVheader + newInfo);
```

This issue has been described here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12060
In short: Expo Media library is able to save image/video/audio assets so it will fail with other file types. Weirdly enough it was working fine with `.pdf` and `.csv` up to Android 10.

In the link above, and also on stackoverflow there are solutions using `StorageAccessFramework`. However, the user needs to create a subdirectory inside Downloads every time a file needs to be saved. I would like to make it automatically without any popups (after permission is granted).
The destination folder doesn't matter as long as it is accessible by the user later.

Comment: In the meantime I'm saving the files with the extension .jpg or .mp4 and renaming them afterwards. That works fine but adds and extra step. It is also very complicated for non-developers to change file extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaLibrary only works with media files (.mp4, .mp3, .jpg), so it's not possible to create .pdf or .csv file extensions. More about it [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7018). However, it can still create files with contents of .pdf or .csv using media file extensions.
In the following code, `asset` is pointing to a file containing a comma-separated values string.

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';

export async function saveCSV() {
      
  const permission = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
  if (permission.status != 'granted') {
    console.log("Permission not Granted!")
    return;
  }
  
  // CSVLocation
  const directoryUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory;
  const fileUri = directoryUri + `formData.mp4`;
  
  // Save to DCIM folder
  const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri);
  
  try {
    const album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync('forms');
    if (album == null) {
      await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('forms', asset, true);
    } else {
      await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album, true)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('File Saved Successfully!');
        })
        .catch((err: string) => {
          console.log('Error In Saving File!', err);
        });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

}
```

This will generate a file with comma-separated values (CSV) and .mp4 extension.
This files are intended to be exported and used by windows users. They will rename them with the following `.bat` script:

```
@ECHO OFF
rename *.mp4 *.csv
```

After renaming they will be fully functional csv files. The same process will work on .pdf or other file extensions unsuported by ExpoMediaLibrary